# How to convert numpy functions to tensorflow operations without errors

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, gradient

I am building a custom loss that takes into account the gradient and laplacian of an image

```
def custom_loss_mse_GradLap(X_true, X_pred):

  X_pred_GradLap = np.asarray(model_CompGradientLaplacian(X_pred))
  X_true_GradLap = np.asarray(model_CompGradientLaplacian(X_true))

  #define the parametrs
  alpha          = np.array([1/3,1/3,1/3])
  # mse for field

  loss1   = K.mean(K.square(X_pred-X_true), axis=-1)                             

  # mse for gradient
  loss2 = K.mean(K.square(X_pred_GradLap[0]-X_true_GradLap[0]), axis=-1)

  # mse for laplacian
  loss3 = K.mean(K.square(X_pred_GradLap[1]-X_true_GradLap[1]),axis=-1)

  return alpha[0] * loss1 + alpha[1] * loss2 + alpha[2] * loss3
```

But I have problems computing the gradient and laplacien. 
I tried the following but it raises errors

```
input=tf.placeholder(shape=(64,64),dtype=tf.float32)
def calc_grad(x):
  return np.gradient(x)
grad = Lambda(lambda x:tf.py_func(calc_grad,[x],tf.float32))
model_grad = Model(input_data,grad)
```

Comment: What errors does it raise? + If you're using numpy for calculations why do you need tensorflow at all?

Comment: Does `tensorflow` have methods or functions to convert a `placeholder` to an array?  Don't count on `np.asarray(...)` to properly convert your object(s) to arrays.  `tensorflow` should know something about `numpy`, but it doesn't work in the other direction.

Comment: I solved the problem by using filters to compute the grad and laplacian and apply regular convolutions.